# Serverless Framework - create postman collection with generated API ID

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, scripting, serverless-framework

using Serverless build on node docker with localstack and using python lambdas, I want to hand the project to someone, allow them to build and run it using Docker. This is fine the only problem is my endpoints are generated with a random API ID everytime and the less explaining I have to do for this the better.

I need to be able to either

1. Export the API endpoints to a file serverless-plugin-export-endpoints https://github.com/ar90n/serverless-plugin-export-endpoints
   I tried doing this with this plugin but ran into issue described in my other question which you can find below in my comment. this question also has more detail around my project.
2. Use a custom domain with localstack, serverless and docker, not sure this is possible?
3. Any other solution that can get me a postman collection whether it be exported or one i make myself hardcoded because I know what it will look like when its deployed.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried using a plugin to export the endpoints but ran into issues, detailed that questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67801275/docker-adding-command-in-dockerfile-results-in-stack-validation-error

Comment: I don't use postman but [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) which is a similar tool and [there you can use variables](https://support.insomnia.rest/article/170-environment-variables) to hold the base url of your api. I am sure postman has a similar feature. This way you only need to fill in one thing after having generated it.

Comment: Yea it's just exporting it is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use the second option - "Use a custom domain with localstack, serverless and docker".

Use virtual host like Nginx and add a custom domain in it and use it for your API. You can add the nginx virtual host file in the docker image and can handover the same.

And add environment variables for your collection which will include the API endpoint as well.